# Possible error in numpy np.in1d() routine

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I was testing the numpy `np.in1d()` routine to see if it works as expected because I need to include it in a program. Namely I tried

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(0, 1, 0.1)
>>> y = np.arange(0.5, 1, 0.2)
>>> x
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
>>> y
array([0.5, 0.7, 0.9])
>>> np.in1d(x, y)
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, False, False, False])
```

The result of the last evaluation seems to be an error. From what is stated in [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) I would expect it to be instead

```
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False, True, False, True])
```

I am working with Python 3.7.3 and NumPy 1.16.1. The first time I tried it was on the command line and then replicated the above MWE in the IDLE to see if it was a bug or something but the result was identical.

Is this a known issue? Is it a problem with how numpy defines `dtype` for `np.arange()`? Or is it something else, like the Python/numpy version?

---

EDIT: I tried doing the same operation but with integers instead and the result is as I originally expected. In particular I did:

```
>>> x = np.arange(10)
>>> y = np.arange(5, 10, 2)
>>> np.in1d(x, y)
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False, True])
```

This makes me suspect it is a bug related to the `dtype` of the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the way numpy.arange rounds numbers. You can see it more clearly when you do this:

```
y[2]

Output 0.8999999999999999
```

and

```
x[9]

Output 0.9
```

They are not equal. So you get the False in the last position.

However, if you were to construct the ndarrays like this:

```
a = np.array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9])
b = np.array([0.5, 0.7, 0.9])
```

and then:

```
np.in1d(a, b)
```

**Output:**

```
array([False, False, False, False, False,  True, False,  True, False,
        True])
```

You get the output you seek.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. But since there are such inaccuracies in how numpy manages floats then shouldn't the `in1d` routine include a margin of error?

Comment: @SV It isn't the way `numpy` manages floats per se, but it is the way numpy.arange generates floats. That is why I added the a-b example in my answer, it is to show where the issues lies. When you (somewhat) manually construct the array in numpy out of a list etc., you don't face that problem.

Comment: @SV `in1d` is meant to be roughly equivalent to `np.array([item in b for item in a])`, and the `in` keyword has no such margin of error. It might be nice to be able to specify a margin parameter yourself, but it breaks the symmetry and might give surprising results. It's not too hard to write the margin of error in yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with `np.in1d`, but rather has to do with the implementation of floating point numbers. Unfortunately, decimal numbers are not typically exactly expressible in finite-length binary, so there are small inaccuracies in floats. Check it yourself:

```
print(x[7],y[1]) #result: 0.7000000000000001 0.7 
print(x[9],y[2]) #result: 0.9 0.8999999999999999
```